# Play Video in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

```
{
       xtype:'panel',
       flex:1,
       layout:'vbox',
       items:
       [
         {
           xtype: 'video', 
           id:'videoPlayer', 
           enableControls: true,
           url: filePath,
           loop: false,
           flex:1,
           posterUrl: thumbPath,
         },

         {
           xtype:'panel',
           cls: 'side_detail_bottom_title',  
           html: 'Video Title: '+title,
         }
      ]
```

}

I am trying to play a remote video from a server. Problem is that it only play mp4 videos. It doesn't play avi and some other video formats.

Is there any restrictions on file formats? or something wrong with code or xtype:video?

Btw I am trying it in chrome.

Comment: 3gp and mov formats are working for me

Comment: I need to play mp4, ogg, avi, mov, wmv, flv, ogv, and webm. only mp4 plays and all other formats are not working

Answer (score 0):

the video element officialy supports mp4, webm and ogg.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

If you provide the urls to these 3 formats the browser will use the format that it supports automatically.

For example, iOS supports MP4 and Android supports WebM. Provide urls to these formats and iOS will automatically play the MP4. Android will play the WebM.

http://caniuse.com/video